# Joining Same Table using Different Fields Based on Previous Values

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to join 2 tables based on a value that is present in another table, specifically where a field is null.

Depending on if that field is null, I'd like to execute a LEFT JOIN in a different way.

Example:

```
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT report_transaction_id, line_number, sale_staff_id, item_type, article_id, sale_count, return_count, line_price_inc_vat, merchandise_category 
                       FROM [CRM].[TransactionItems]) ti
          ON th.report_transaction_id = ti.report_transaction_id

CASE ti.article_id WHEN IS NULL THEN

          LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 article_id, merchandise_category, long_desc, division_code, division_desc, group_code, group_desc
                       FROM [CRM].[Products]) p
          ON ti.MERCHANDISE_CATEGORY = p.MERCHANDISE_CATEGORY
ELSE
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT article_id, merchandise_category, long_desc, division_code, division_desc, group_code, group_desc
                       FROM [CRM].[Products]) p
          ON ti.article_id = p.article_id

END
```

The CASE section is the part that is erroring, with INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR CASE. As far as I can see, using CASE isn't going to be a valid way of choosing which of these Joins to use for the Products table, so I was wondering what the correct way would be of determining which join needs to be run,

Thanks.

Comment: Try `CASE WHEN ti.article_id IS NULL THEN`

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately. It's what I originally had before moving the ti.article_id to before WHEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use CASE like that, you will have to do something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 article_id, merchandise_category, long_desc, division_code, division_desc, group_code, group_desc
FROM [CRM].[Products]) p
ON ti.MERCHANDISE_CATEGORY = p.MERCHANDISE_CATEGORY
WHERE ti.article_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT article_id, merchandise_category, long_desc, division_code,  division_desc, group_code, group_desc
FROM [CRM].[Products]) p
ON ti.article_id = p.article_id
WHERE ti.article_id IS NOT NULL
```

Join both subqueries but use the `ti.article_id` in a where clause.

You will have to use a different alias for the 2nd subquery (e.g. 'q') and in the main SELECT statement, use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to return the value, e.g:

```
SELECT ISNULL(p.article_id, q.article_id)
```

Comment: I was afraid this was the case with the CASE keyword and joins.

I have tried the solution recommended about (Using q for the second join, and having to substitute WHERE for AND) and didn't receive the results expected. All the fields from the p/q table returned null values.

Comment: Scratch that, there was a problem with the data I was using. This now appears to work for NULL fields and for article IDs that can be matched to the products table, but not article IDs that cannot. However, this is a great deal further than I've gotten up to now, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with If else statement?

Comment: I've been trying to get it to set a variable that an If Else statement could use, but haven't been having much luck with it. An If statement doesn't seem to want to take a field being null as an arguement

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the problem may be in your use of TOP 1 in this subquery:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 article_id, merchandise_category, long_desc, division_code,
              division_desc, group_code, group_desc
 FROM [CRM].[Products])
```

As written, TOP 1 here mean, "Independent of everything else in this query, randomly pick one row from [CRM].[Products], and use that row for my join"

I assume this isn't the intent - in which case, you need to clarify (in English if you don't know the SQL syntax) exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the TOP 1.

This is really a situation where it'd be helpful if you provided some sample data and showed desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately the TOP 1 appears to be part of the requirement for what I am trying to do. If the article ID isn't present, then the merchandise_category field is to be used to join the information. The merchandise_category field isn't unique, meaning there could be thousands of records per merchandise_category. Selecting one at random appears to be the current accepted requirement (Sorting the Products by an additional field results in the query taking far too long to process)

Comment: Yeah, but your syntax isn't saying, "Pick one row (randomly) from all the rows with matching merchandise_category".  It is saying, "pick one row (randomly) from entire table".